# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'C:\Project\node_modules\zlib\lib'

Tags: reactjs

I just started to work on a react project and I encounter a problem when I input the command "npm start". I get the error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'C:\Project\node_modules\zlib\lib'" and I don't find any way to install the missing module *zlib_bindings*.

Do you have any idea of how I could fix this ?

Thanks for reading ! :)

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by editing the node_modules

open `node_modules` and search on zlib Library
you will find: **lib** folder, open this folder then click on **zlib.js**

```js
module.exports = require('./zlib_bindings');
```

the problem is this module is not find, that's because there is no `./zlib_binding` in lib folder.
so the solution is making a file in the **lib** folder, name: `zlib_binding.js`